# ASP.NET MVC 2 - Uploaded image validation - Is there more to do than checking file extensions and MIME types?

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-2, file-upload

I have a somewhat complex edit model coming into (surprise surprise) an Edit ActionMethod.  One of the model's properties is a `HttpPostedFileBase` object, which I'd like to validate and display the validation results on the form if the file isn't legit.  To this end, I've already started work on a custom ValidationAttribute object, based on `RequiredAttribute` (see [How to validate uploaded file in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388812/how-to-validate-uploaded-file-in-asp-net-mvc/6388927#6388927) for an idea of where I'm going).

Is there anything I can do in addition to checking the file extension and MIME type to ensure that, yes, the file being uploaded is indeed an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the file extension or the MIME type is a start, but if you want to be sure you are dealing with a valid image you need to open the file and check its headers.

You can find more information on this in the following post:

[Validate image from file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210650/validate-image-from-file-in-c)