# MVC3 How to check if HttpPostedFileBase is an image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, httppostedfilebase

I have a controller like this:

```
public ActionResult Upload (int id, HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
{
....
}
```

How can I make sure that uploadFile is an image (jpg, png etc.)

I have tried with

```
using (var bitmapImage = new Bitmap (uploadFile.InputStream)) {..}
```

which throws an ArgumentException if bitmapImage can not be created.

Is there a better way for example by looking at uploadFile.FileName?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can check the `HttpPostedFileBase` object's properties for this

- ContentType
- FileName (check the file extensions, which you already know about :) )

[image]

Also here is a small method, I have prepared which you can use/extend...

```
private bool IsImage(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file.ContentType.Contains("image"))
    {
        return true; 
    }

    string[] formats = new string[] { ".jpg", ".png", ".gif", ".jpeg" }; // add more if u like...

    // linq from Henrik Stenbæk
    return formats.Any(item => file.FileName.EndsWith(item, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```

I have also written an article on this [here](http://yassershaikh.com/how-to-check-if-an-uploaded-file-is-an-image-or-not-in-asp-net-mvc-3/)

Comment: Thaks - I have changed the foreach to: `return formats.Any(item => file.FileName.EndsWith(item, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));`

Answer (score 20):

You could check the file name and extension and MIME type but that might not be reliable because the user could simply rename the file before uploading. Here's a reliable way to achieve that by looking at the contents of the file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6388927/29407

You could of course extend this to other known image type formats than PNG, like this:

```
public class ValidateFileAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var file = value as HttpPostedFileBase;
        if (file == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (file.ContentLength > 1 * 1024 * 1024)
        {
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            var allowedFormats = new[] 
            { 
                ImageFormat.Jpeg, 
                ImageFormat.Png, 
                ImageFormat.Gif, 
                ImageFormat.Bmp 
            };

            using (var img = Image.FromStream(file.InputStream))
            {
                return allowedFormats.Contains(img.RawFormat);
            }
        }
        catch { }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think bringing across the example code, you should probably have removed the limitation wanted on the other post of 'not exceeding 1MB' by removing the 2nd if statement - doesn't help in answering this question.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can check it on client side thru html attribute 'accept' to filter the file asap:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.HomeDeviceImage, new { @type = "file", @accept = "image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" })
```

this will only show filetypes defined in your accept attribute as default. Beware, user can still change filetye to "All files", with this in mind, better check this:

[Solved concern](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/282302-applying-javascript-to-check-file-size-and-extension/)
, a javascript snippet to check extension, and then do some editing to disable button like:

```
            $('input:submit').attr('disabled', true);
```

until file extension is correct. nevertheless have it checked on server side. :)