# How to send multiple parameters using Html.BeginForm() in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, blogs, html.beginform

Actually I want to send the image and the text in the textbox to the controller...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
         @Html.Label("UserName:") <input type="text" id="txtImg" name="txtImg" /><br /><br />
            @Html.Label("Upload:")<input type="file" name="image" /><br/>    
        <div id="Preview">
        Preview
    </div>

        <input class="btn btn-success btnUpload" type="submit" value="upload" />

    }
```

and I am trying to retrieve them in the controller in the below way:

```
 public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase image,string txtImg)
```

but I am not getting the textbox value..Is anything wrong withe code?

I have my sample code like this.

```
Controller:
    public ActionResult Upload()
            {
                BlobStorageServices _blobstorageservice = new BlobStorageServices();
                CloudBlobContainer container = _blobstorageservice.GetCloudBlobContainer();
                List<string> blobs = new List<string>();
                //List<BlobModel> models = BlobManager.getBlobs();
                foreach (var blobItem in container.ListBlobs())
                {
                    blobs.Add(blobItem.Uri.ToString());

                }
                return View(blobs);
            }
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Upload(string txtImg,HttpPostedFileBase image)
            {
                if (image.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    BlobStorageServices _blobstorageservice = new BlobStorageServices();            
                    CloudBlobContainer container = _blobstorageservice.GetCloudBlobContainer();
                    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(image.FileName);
                 //BlobManager.insertBlobUri(new BlobImage { Uri = blob.Uri.ToString() });
                // string text = model.Name;
                  BlobManager.insertBlobUri(new BlobModel {Name=txtImg,Uri=blob.Uri.ToString()});
                    blob.UploadFromStream(image.InputStream);
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Upload");
            }

    View
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
             @Html.Label("UserName:") <input type="text" id="txtImg" name="txtImg" /><br /><br />      
                @Html.Label("Upload:")<input type="file" name="image" id="upload"/><br/>    
            <div id="Preview">
            Preview<img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
        </div>

            <input class="btn btn-success btnUpload" type="submit" value="upload" />

        }

    <table style="border:1">

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {

            <tr style="border:1">

                <td><img src="@item" alt="image" class="img-responsive" width="100" height="100" /></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-primary Delete"  id="@item" onclick="deleteImage('@item');">Delete</button></td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-primary Download" href="@item" target="_blank">Download Image</a></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-primary Download"  onclick="updateImage('@item');">UpdateImage</button></td>
            </tr>

        }
```

I am sending the blobs directly into the view , that is the problem basically..How to use a model to insert text,bloburl,image?

Comment: Does it work if you change the order of the parameters to `Upload(string txtImg, HttpPostedFileBase image)`?

Answer (score 3):

Visit [Uploading/Displaying Images in MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255882/how-to-upload-image-display-image-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

This helped me alot for uploading images

In Terms of retrieving data from the View to controller a better way is to use a ViewModel like

```
public class ExampleViewModel
{
    public string Image {get; set;}
    public string Text {get; set;}
}
```

and your view would look something like

```
@model YourProject.Models.ExampleViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("ExampleController","Home",FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Text)

    <input id="Image" type="file" name="Image" data-val="true" />

}
```

and the controller

```
public ActionResult ExampleController(ExampleViewModel model)
{
    //Not sure how you wanted to get the image so I just put this in here
    foreach (string file in Request.Files)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase hpf=Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFileBase;
        if(hpf.ContentLengh==0)
        continue;
        string folderPath = Server.MapPath("~/yourFolderPath");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);

        string savedFileName = Server.MapPath("~/yourFolderPath/" + hpf.FileName);
        hpf.SaveAs(savedFileName);
        model.Image="~/yourFolderPath/" + hpf.FileName;
    }
    //this variable is getting the text from the ViewModel
    string text=model.Text;
}
```

Hope this helps :)