# Bulk Image Upload from client machine to server in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc-4, silverlight, image-uploading

I have a bulk image upload functionality in my MVC4 application(with out file upload control). We have a Excel template with Image data such as (image name, description, alt text and image path where the image is located). The Excel file contains minimum 100 rows.

I have a page in my application where the user can upload this Excel. Once the user upload this excel file and clicks on submit button, all the image data (name, description, alt text) should insert to database and the image should be uploaded to the server from the path specified in Excel file.

Inserting the data to database part is working fine as i am reading the excel file using oledb to datatable and inserting to database.

The problem is uploading the image to the server from the path specified in Excel. The images are located in client machine. 
Can anyone please help me how i can achieve this bulk image upload functionality in ASP.Net MVC. I found many articles on bulk image upload but they are using file upload control which i don't want to use.

Many Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: One of my friend suggested me to use silver light component to upload images from client machine to server. can any one have any idea on how to use silverlight in asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explanation to upload files into a ASP MVC application.

[Upload files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255882/uploading-displaying-images-in-mvc-4)

I Suggest you to go Async File Uploads method with AJAX. You can find info here :

[Async File Uploads](http://weblogs.asp.net/bryansampica/AsyncMVCFileUpload)

Take a look at this scripts

[14 Best HTML5 jQuery File Upload Scripts](http://designscrazed.org/html5-jquery-file-upload-scripts/)

Comment: hi Turrican, Thanks for the immediate response. My requirement is not to use file upload control bcoz i need to upload the data and image at single shot for hundreds of images. One of my friend suggested me to use silver light component. can any one have any idea on how to use silverlight in asp.net mvc?

Comment: Don't use silverlight or flash there are deprecated web frontend architectures. Use javascript instead (is the frontend standard). You can upload all files at single shoot using a custom file/image uploader with support for multi-file implementing ajax. Take a look here http://designscrazed.org/html5-jquery-file-upload-scripts/

Comment: Anyway, if you don't want to upload files via browser, you can make a windows desktop application.