# display uploaded photo in div

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have form like this

[image]

I must do file uploader which will display uploaded image here (in circle).

OK I can upload image and save on server using [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255882/uploading-displaying-images-in-mvc-4) or something similar it But how can I display it in circle immediately?

And is it necessary to save photo on hard drive?

Comment: will u share the code ?

Comment: you want to display after selecting image?

Comment: @fanjo yeah after selecting

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @GiorgiPilishvili Will you provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display image immediate after selecting with the help of jQuery.

### Here is Html

```
 <div class="formRow">
    <label for="contact_name" class="fieldLabel">
        File Upload
    </label>
    <div class="field">
        <input type="file" name="FileUpload" id="FileUpload" />
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="formRow">
    <label for="contact_name" class="fieldLabel">
    </label>
    <div id="dvPreview">
    </div>
 </div>
```

### jQuery

```
jQuery(function ($) {        
    jQuery('#FileUpload').change(function () {
        jQuery('#dvPreview').html("");
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png|.bmp)$/;
        if (regex.test($(this).val().toLowerCase())) {
            if (jQuery.browser.msie && parseFloat(jQuery.browser.version) <= 9.0) {
                jQuery('#dvPreview').show();
                jQuery('#dvPreview')[0].filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader").src = jQuery(this).val();
            }
            else {
                if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                    jQuery('#dvPreview').show();
                    jQuery('#dvPreview').append("<img style='width:200px; height:100px' />");
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        jQuery('#dvPreview img').attr("src", e.target.result);
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
                } else {
                    alert("This browser does not support FileReader.");
                }
            }
        }
        else {

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you return the view after uploading. then please return image path in model or viewbag and on View level check if there is some value in that then populate it in image tag.. this can be done asynchronusly also.

Comment: I dont want to display it after returning view. I want to that directly after upload

Comment: Yes so you have to use ajax for that