# How to save uploaded image in database and show in view using .Net MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to save uploaded image in database and show in view using .Net MVC but no success.

Here is my code.

Model:

```
    public class TeamStartup
    {

        public string thumb { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller:

```
    public class CityDetailController : Controller
    {

//Save Team Member StartUp  Picture
        private string SaveTeamMemberPicture(HttpPostedFileBase thumb)

        {
            string fileName = default(string);
            string savedPath = default(string);
            string[] validExtensions = new string[4] { ".png", ".jpg", ".gif", ".jpeg" };

            if (thumb != null && thumb.ContentLength > 0)
            {

                fileName = Path.GetFileName(thumb.FileName);
                var fileExt = new FileInfo(fileName).Extension;

                if (!validExtensions.Contains(fileExt.ToLower()))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Image type Invalid");
                }
                if (thumb.ContentLength > 1048576)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "file size limit exceeds (Max 1MB)");
                }

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                    fileName = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadsPath"] + "/Avatars/City"), fileName);

                    thumb.SaveAs(path);
                    savedPath = fileName;
                }
            }
            return savedPath;
        }
}
```

It doesn't save and show anything in database, Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uploading/Displaying Images in MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255882/uploading-displaying-images-in-mvc-4)

Answer (score 0):

`HttpPostedFileBase` provides `InputStream` property. Use it to get the actual binary version of the image. Usually it is Base64 encoded version of the image. Save this in the database.

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(thumb.InputStream)) 
{
  let image = sr.ReadToEnd();

  //save this string 'image' in DB
}
```

To display it, return the Base64 string (saved in DB) to response in image tag by setting its `src` attribute to `data:image/png;base64, <Base64String>`. Check below example.

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
        9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

Answer (score 0):

change your model:

```
  public string ImageName{ get; set; }
```

change your view:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Posts", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

```html
 <input type="file" name="ImgUp" id="ImgUp"  accept="image/*"/>
```

And Your Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase ImgUp)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if (ImgUp != null)
            {
                post.ImageName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(ImgUp.FileName);
                ImgUp.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/Images/" + post.ImageName));

            }

            _dbContext.InsertPost(post);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }

    }
```

Your Image save In Your Root Project In Images Folder And For Display Image:

```html
 <img class="imgindex" src="/Images/@Model.ImageName" />
```