# Making HttpPostedFileBase Required in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the below code in my model and I want to make it required just I can other data types like string by adding [Required] but it is not working on this type.

```
public HttpPostedFileBase Docs
{
get;
set;
}
```

`@Html.FormTextBoxFor(m => m.Docs)` this is how I am creating it in the view.

Can someone please tell me what I have to do so that it displays a Required attribute for the HttpPostedFileBase  type.

Thanks

Comment: I have a lot of model bindings like this that  I wanted this solution for. Is there no other better solution than adding javascript to all the bindings.

Comment: You would need to check both client and server side. Can you post your custom FormTestBoxFor HTML helper? I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126472/is-there-a-way-to-validate-incoming-httppostedfilebase-files-in-mvc-2 this worked for me. Thanks